# How to get tweets using Twitter4J without credentials?

Tags: android, twitter4j

I am using the example at this [link](https://github.com/yusuke/twitter4j/blob/master/twitter4j-examples/src/main/java/twitter4j/examples/search/SearchTweets.java) to make a search in the Twitter.

This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        searchTweets();
    }

    private void searchTweets() {
        Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
        try {
            Query query = new Query("android");
            QueryResult result;
            do {
                result = twitter.search(query);
                List<Status> tweets = result.getTweets();
                for (Status tweet : tweets) {
                    System.out.println("@" + tweet.getUser().getScreenName() + " - " + tweet.getText());
                }
            } while ((query = result.nextQuery()) != null);
            System.exit(0);
        } catch (TwitterException te) {
            te.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Failed to search tweets: " + te.getMessage());
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

I am using twitter4j-core-3.0.3

I am facing this error message:

```
Unable to start activity {...MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Authentication credentials are missing. See http://twitter4j.org/configuration.html for the detail.
```

But, why do I have to set some twitter credential to get the tweets?

Is there some wrong with my code?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authentication is required since API 1.1, as its [documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview#Authentication_required_on_all_endpoints) says:

> In version 1.1, we're requiring applications to authenticate all of their requests with OAuth 1.0a or Application-only authentication. Not only will this visibility allow us to prevent abusive behavior, but it will also help us to further understand how categories of applications are using the API. We'll apply that understanding to better meet the needs of developers as we continue to evolve the platform. At this time, all authentication requires user context, but in the coming weeks we'll be pushing out support for a form of authentication not requiring a user context.

Comment: Yeah man. You are right. So long time until some answer, but thank you anyway.

Comment: I know, too late ... but it can be helpful for someone looking for something similar, like me, when I entered here searching in Google.

Answer (score 1):

I use the scribe library for authentification with the OAuth protocol for lots of sort of api , like twitter for example , i hope this info can help you.

https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java

Comment: Long time until some answer, but thank you anyway. Maybe someone can see this like a reference. I don't remember how I've resolved this issue. I think I've created a profile and use its credentials to ask the tweets.